# bayes probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

Suppose you have a test X to diagnose influenza.

Test X is 90% positive when the patient is flu, and Test X is 90% negative when the patient is not flu.

Now, suppose people in the world have flu with a 10% chance.
What is the probability that when a patient is positive for test X, the patient is actually flu?
_____%

is this using bayes such as 
p(f|positive)= (1/10 * 90/100) / (0.1*0.9 + 0.9*0.9) =0.1 
am i right?

Comment: The denominator is not okay. I think it should be $P\left(p\right)=P\left(p\mid f\right)P\left(f\right)+P\left(p\mid f^{\complement}\right)P\left(f^{\complement}\right)=0.9\times0.1+0.1\times0.9$ with $p$ for positive. Observe that your value is quite high.

Comment: @drhab thanks do you mean (1/10 * 90/100) / (0.1*0.9 + 0.1*0.9) ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @devss It is not really a helpful test. If you want to know if  a patient has a flu  you can also use a fair coin,